# How can I add 1 column to df1 with values from df2 columns (df2.s2 or df2.s3) based on values of df1.c2?

Tags: python, pandas

df1 has col : c1, c2, c3

and df2 has c1, s2, s3, s4

For df2, c1 is the key, every row has a unique value, but for df1 c1 is not unique for each row.

I want to make a new c4 in df1 where the values are given by this logic/pseudocode (for each row):

```
loop over df1 rows:
    loop over df2 rows:
        if df1.c1 == df2.c1 then
            if c2 == 2 then
                c4 = s2
            else if c2 == 3
                c4 = s3
            else if c2 == 4
            c4 = s4
```

With the merge function I can do this when I have a simpler problem, where c2 == 1 for all rows. But for a more complex dataset with multiple values for c2 I need the column c5 to contain a different value that is available in df2 depending on the value of c2.

For example:
df1:

```
    c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   15
1   1   3   13
2   2   2   14
```

df2:

```
    c1  s2  s3  s4
0   0   10  20  30
1   1   11  21  31
2   2   9   19  29
```

then the result should be:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   15  21
1   1   3   13  31
2   2   2   14  19
```

The values of c2 are integers 0,1,...20 and I can also have the name of the columns of df2 to be numbers, so: s1,0,1,...20

What I do for now:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[["c1","s1","s2","s3","s4"]], on=['c1',], how='left')
df1["c4"] = 999
for i in range(2,5):
    df1[df1.c2 == i,"c4"] = df1.loc[df1.c2 == i,'s'+str(i)]
    del df1["s"+str(i)]
```

Comment: It is better show u the df1 and df2 and your expected output

Comment: @user7867665, this isn't the best solution, but have you considered nested `np.where` statements? the benefit is it clearly matches the logic you have already laid out, so it might be the way to go if performance is not an issue.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis performance is the main issue. It's a very big dataset, and it actually has more columns that these

Comment: @Wen I added an example

Comment: I've also put my solution, which is not too slow